# Skipping lines with a special charachter (!/#) and empty lines

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

Im new in vb.net programming...
I would like to read a .txt file and skipping the description by special charachters (!) and the empty lines.

[Picture of the .txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz1fW.png)

> !Metric Table
>   !Diameter;Tolerance;Angle
>
> M3
>   3;6H;60
>
> !BSP Table
>   !Diameter;Tolerance;Angle
>
> G1/8
>   1/8;--;55

How can i get only the other lines?

```
If File.StartsWith("!") then ....
```

I struggle with this

Thank you for your Help :-)

Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: You have to read the file line by line.  Research this.

Comment: Now ask yourself how you are going to know what the data represents by ignoring the indicators.  Dont add pictures of code, data or text.
 [Picture of a downvote](https://i.imgur.com/jbaF43Q.jpg)

Comment: You will need to loop over every line in the file, using your `If` statement to check the current line in the loop.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to loop with a if statement?

Comment: This is easy stuff to google.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a tutorial site and you should search this yourself, but This should do it. Below is a function to read through the lines in a text file. If the line starts with a "!" or is empty, it will not be added to the `result` list.

```
Private Function ReadValidLinesFromFile(filename As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim result As New List(Of String)
    For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(filename)
        If Not line.StartsWith("!") And Not line = "" Then
            result.Add(line)
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

To use it, assign it to a list(of String) object similar to this

```
'An list you created earlier
Dim myList As List(Of String)

'somewhere in your code
myList = ReadValidLinesFromFile("replace this with your path and filename")
```